# Collapse/Transpose Columns of a DataFrame Based on Repeating - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame `sample_df` like this,

```
   id   pd  pd_dt      pd_tp    pd.1    pd_dt.1     pd_tp.1 pd.2    pd_dt.2     pd_tp.2
0  1    100 per year   468      200     per year    400     300     per year    320
1  2    100 per year   60       200     per year    890     300     per year    855
```

I need my output like this,

```
id pd   pd_dt     pd_tp
1  100  per year  468
1  200  per year  400
1  300  per year  320
2  100  per year  60
2  200  per year  890
2  300  per year  855
```

I tried the following,

```
sample_df.stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)
```

This does not work. 
I have `pd`, `pd_dt`, `pd_tp` are repeating with `.1`, `.2` .. values.

I have How can I achieve output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy split to split it into n arrays and concetanate them back together. Then repeat the id column by the number of rows in your new dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(np.split(df.iloc[:,1:].values, (df.shape[1] - 1)/3, axis=1)))
new_df.columns = ['pd','pd_dt','pd_tp']
new_df['id'] = pd.concat([df.id] * (new_df.shape[0]//2), ignore_index=True)
new_df.sort_values('id')
```

Result:

```
    pd     pd_dt pd_tp  id
0  100  per year   468   1
2  200  per year   400   1
4  300  per year   320   1
1  100  per year    60   2
3  200  per year   890   2
5  300  per year   855   2
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `pd.wide_to_long`, but with some tweak since your first few columns do not share the same patterns with the rest:

```
# rename
df.columns = [x+'.0' if '.' not in x and x != 'id' else x
                for x in df.columns]

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['pd','pd_dt','pd_tp'],
                i='id', j='order', sep='.')
```

Output:

```
           pd     pd_dt  pd_tp
id order                      
1  0      100  per year    468
2  0      100  per year     60
1  1      200  per year    400
2  1      200  per year    890
1  2      300  per year    320
2  2      300  per year    855
```

Comment: nice, this is totally new to me. Is there a way to get `id` as I have it  my desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
dt_mask=df.columns.str.contains('dt')
tp_mask=df.columns.str.contains('tp')
new_df=pd.DataFrame()
new_df['pd']=df[df.columns[~(dt_mask|tp_mask)]].stack().reset_index(level=1,drop='level_1')
new_df['pd_dt']=df[df.columns[dt_mask]].stack().reset_index(level=1,drop='level_1')
new_df['pd_tp']=df[df.columns[tp_mask]].stack().reset_index(level=1,drop='level_1')
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(new_df)

   id   pd     pd_dt  pd_tp
0   1  100  per_year    468
1   1  200  per_year    400
2   1  300  per_year    320
3   2  100  per_year     60
4   2  200  per_year    890
5   2  300  per_year    855
```

Comment: I get an error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` for line `new_df['pd_dt']=df[df.columns[dt_mask]].stack().res`...